# Beam template for dataflow will not upload to bucket

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've followed all the quickstarts/documentation for creating Java-based dataflow templates.
The steps I've found and done is:

1) Create the project:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
      -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.beam \
      -DarchetypeArtifactId=beam-sdks-java-maven-archetypes-examples \
      -DarchetypeVersion=2.22.0 \
      -DgroupId=com.example \
      -DartifactId=JsonToBucket \
      -Dversion="0.1" \
      -Dpackage=com.example.dataflow \
      -DinteractiveMode=false
```

2) mvn clean && mvn compile

This reports build success

3) Compile and upload to bucket

```
mvn compile exec:java -Pdataflow-runner \                      
-Dexec.mainClass=com.example.dataflow.JsonToBucket -Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false  \   
-Dexec.args="--runner=DataflowRunner \
--project=PROJECT \
--stagingLocation=gs://some-bucket/staging \
--templateLocation=gs://some-bucket/beam_templates/DisruptivePubSubToBucket"
```

The output of this is:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.example:jsonToBucket >----------------------
[INFO] Building jsonToBucket 0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ jsonToBucket ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /somepath/jsonToBucket/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ jsonToBucket ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to /somepath/jsonToBucket/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) @ jsonToBucket ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.161 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-19T14:05:52+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

No files are uploaded to the bucket set in step 3.

What could be wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming that JsonToBucket is the class where you are defining the pipeline. Can you update the question with the code of this class? Specifically I'm interested on seeing how it is implementing the pipeline options

Comment: Hi. The problem was a real small thing, the run() method was never triggered. Thanks for getting me on the right path.

Comment: I included your comment as an answer and marked it as community wiki. Feel free to edit it further to add more context of what was the issue

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the `run()` method. Taken from @gixen comment:

> The problem was a real small thing, the run() method was never triggered